# Dificuldade para passar coluna no update como parâmetro na função Python3 com SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Estou usando SQLAlchemy para trabalhar com tabelas de banco de dados. Estou criando classes para as devidas tabelas, onde tenho como métodos dessas classes, insert, filter_all(), etc.

Estou usando a seguinte classe com seus métodos:

```
class Veiculos(base):
    __tablename__ = "veiculos"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    marca =  Column(String(20))
    modelo = Column(String(20))
    ano = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, str_marca="None", str_modelo="None", int_ano="None"):
        """
        :param str_marca: (str).
        :param str_modelo: (str).
        :param  int_ano: (int).
        """
        self.marca =  str_marca
        self.modelo = str_modelo
        self.ano = int_ano

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< Veículo {}, {}, {} >".format(self.marca, self.modelo, self.ano)

    def insert(self):
        session.add(self)
        session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
        return  session.query(self).filter_by(**kwargs).all()

    @classmethod
    def select_all(self):        
        return session.query(self)

    @classmethod
    def update(self, int_id, **kwargs):
        id = int_id
        print('keys', kwargs.keys())
        print('values', kwargs.values())
        print('-----')
        print('Nome ANTES da alteração:', session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).one().marca)
        session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update(**kwargs)
        # session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update(**kwargs)
        # session.commit()
        print('Nome DEPOIS da alteração:', session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).one().marca)
```

Meu problema está no seguinte método:

```
@classmethod
        def update(self, int_id, **kwargs):
            id = int_id
            print('keys', kwargs.keys())
            print('values', kwargs.values())
            print('-----')
            print('Nome ANTES da alteração:', session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).one().marca)
            session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update(**kwargs)
            # session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update(**kwargs)
            # session.commit()
            print('Nome DEPOIS da alteração:', session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).one().marca)
```

Especificamente nessas linhas:

```
session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update(**kwargs)
session.commit()
```

Onde o **filter_by(id=id)** busca corretamente, mas a parte **update(**kwargs)** diz que não existe o argumento.

```
Erro:
Nome ANTES da alteração: CLEBER
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Projetos/estudoPostgres11/SAO.py", line 97, in <module>
    veiculos.update(id, **busca)
  File "c:/Projetos/estudoPostgres11/SAO.py", line 52, in update
    session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update(**kwargs)
TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'marca'
```

Essa é a chamada da função:

```
veiculos = Veiculos()
    id = 1
    busca = {"marca": "TUDO"}
    veiculos.update(id, **busca)
```

O que estou fazendo de errado para não funcionar o update desse modo?

Comment: E como você executaria isto manualmente `session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update(...)`?

Comment: Manualmente ficaria "session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update({coluna: valor})."
Mas passando isso por parâmetro (**kwargs) na função não funcionou.
Resolvi de outra forma:
Colocar no comentário geral pois aqui não cabe

Comment: Tá, mas este manualmente funcionou? Porque o seu manualmente esta DIFERENTE do teu via kwargs, o teu manualmente é isto `.filter_by(id=id).update({coluna: valor})` e o teu kwargs esta gerando isto `.filter_by(id=id).update(coluna=valor)`, e estou quase certo que isso não é reconhecido pelo sqlalchemy, ele só aceita passado como dict e não é o que teu kwargs esta fazendo, ele esta passando como parametro

Comment: Manualmente funciona. No comentário geral (Resposta), como consegui contornar.

Comment: Não, vc não entendeu, manualmente esta diferente do kwargs, entende uma coisa o kwargs não esta sendo interpretado de forma igual ao manual, entendeu? Era para INTERNAMENTE o kwarg gerar isto: `.filter_by(id=id).update({coluna: valor})`, mas isto de forma dinamica, este deveria ser o equivalente, MAS  da forma que vc escreveu ele esta gerando isto INTERNAMENTE: `.filter_by(id=id).update(coluna=valor)`, e esta forma aqui esta incorreta.

Comment: Entendi.Mas mesmo eu fazendo: .filter_by(id=id).update({kwargs.keys(): kwargs.values()}) ou parecido não funcionou. Podes olhar como contornei e dizer se tinha algo melhor:

Comment: Você esta inventando sintaxes irreais, não adianta inventar as coisas, não é assim que o kwargs funciona, na outra resposta eu colei o link e expliquei, vc primeiro precisa entender como é o manualmente e ajustar ponto a ponto, python facilita em muita coisa, mas não é capaz de adivinhar coisas aleatórias, eu não to criticando, só to dizendo, não invente, isso ai não existe, tem que entender o funcionamento da linguagem vou ver se ajusto aqui e formulo de uma vez a resposta, é qeu eu não gosto de dar o peixe pronto, eu to tentando te ensinar a pesca-lo.

Comment: Sim, entendo. Agradeço a atenção mas consegui resolver conforme resposta publicada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
@classmethod
    def update(self, int_id, **kwargs):
        id = int_id
        for e in kwargs:
            coluna = e
            valor = kwargs[e]                    
        print('Nome ANTES da alteração:', session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).one().marca)
        session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).update({coluna: valor})
        session.commit()
        print('Nome DEPOIS da alteração:', session.query(self).filter_by(id=id).one().marca)
```

A chamada ficou assim:

```
  veiculos = Veiculos()
    id = 1
    busca = {"marca": "TUDO"}
    veiculos.update(id, **busca)
```

Se tiver algo melhor, ficarei grato em saber.